# How do we know what constants can replace variables in an open sentence?

Tags: logic

Consider for example the open sentence,

> *x lives in India*

where 'x' is a variable, which can be substituted by various constants to make declarative sentences.

For instance,

> *Harshit lives in India*
>
> *Carol lives in India*
>
> *Zaid lives in India*

where 'x' has been replaced by constants 'Harshit', 'Carol' and 'Zaid', respectively.

I don't understand how do we exactly come to know which constants can substitute the variables in an open sentence.

I mean, if someone says, significant substitutes are names of people, in this example, I would say why not of pets? Why not just of people of a particular City or ethnicity?

---

Since, this question is from logic, which is a prerequisite (AFAIK) of set theory, I would humbly expect no notions from set theory to be used.

Comment: A *term*, i.e. either a constant or a variable or a complex term made with a function symbol (if any).

Comment: $x+0=1$ is a formula with variable x. You can replace it with 0 or with s(0), i.e.1.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Using the notion of sets only to get across the idea, what I mean to say is how do we decide the domain of the variable? For example, in the example that I gave in the question, how would one decide whether the domain is set of all people, set of people of a particular city, or set of animals who are pets?

Comment: Constants are part pf the language, thus they are specified by the rules of the language.

Comment: "why not of pets?" Maybe the person making the statement doesn't want to study pets. "why not just people of a particular ethnicity?" Maybe the person making the statement doesn't want to restrict their study to people of a particular ethnicity. It all depends on the person making the statement. It depends on what the person making the statement wants to study. How much to restrict or generalize one's domain depends pretty much on one's problem. If one wants to study political beliefs of a particular state, restrict to that state and maybe only to people who vote etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When evaluating or constructing an argument, one typically defines a *domain*, that is, the set of all elements being considered in that specific problem or context. This is also referred to as the *domain of discourse* of *universe of discourse*. The domain can be *restricted* to a certain kind of thing, such as all animals or all people, or the domain can be *unrestricted* so as to include literally everything.

Members of the domain are specifically named things, and they are represented by individual constants such as $a,b,c$ or any of the first $23$ letters of the alphabet. A variable, such as $x$, represents an arbitrary, unnamed element from the domain.

An open sentence, or propositional function, becomes a statement with a definite truth value once every variable therein is either $(1)$ substituted with a constant from the domain or $(2)$ bound to a quantifier. You can substitute **any constant** you wish to produce such a statement, but the choice of constant is usually dictated by the specific problem or argument you're working with. In other words, you may require a specific constant from the domain because that constant appears in other statements, and you may need a subset of statements discussing the same constant in order to apply a desired inference rule. For example, take the argument

$\forall x [Fx \to Gx], Fa \vdash Ma$

where

$F:$ ___ is a folk singer.

$M:$ ___ is a musician.

$a:$ Alice

In general, the choice of domain should consist of all and only those things capable of possessing the relevant properties. So here the domain is appropriately defined as the set of all people because all folk singers and all musicians are people, and only people can be folk singers and musicians.

Note that one can apply universal elimination to $\forall x [Fx \to Mx]$ to obtain $Fb \to Mb$ where $b$ is Bob, and this would result in a perfectly acceptable statement, that is, "If Bob is a folk singer, then Bob is a musician." However, if I'm trying to prove the argument, then obtaining a statement about Bob is not helpful because the argument is about Alice. Among all constants I could choose from, I prefer to instantiate with $a$ corresponding to Alice so that I can obtain $Fa \to Ma$ and derive the conclusion $Ma$ via the inference rule known as Modus Ponens.